Seeking Guidance on GSAP Animation for Diagonal and Horizontal Movement in React
I'm currently developing a feature using React and GSAP in a personal project where elements (spaceships and clouds) animate across the screen in a continuous loop. The spaceships are supposed to move diagonally across the screen at specific angles, while the clouds move horizontally. The main challenge arises with the repositioning of these elements: after exiting the screen, they should reappear from the opposite side to maintain a seamless loop.
My implementation involves an "if" condition to differentiate the movement based on the angle—horizontal movement for clouds (angle = 0) and diagonal for spaceships (angle != 0). While the initial animation sequence works as expected, making the elements reappear from the opposite side has proven to be problematic. Instead of continuing their journey across the screen from where they exited, they reset to their original starting positions.
This issue is particularly perplexing as it interrupts the desired continuous flow of the animation. I have set up a minimal demo to illustrate my current approach and the issue at hand. This setup is supposed to showcase a looped animation effect for each element based on their designated movement patterns.
The minimal demo
In my implementation, I used GSAP's fromTo function to animate the elements based on their designated paths. For horizontal movement (clouds with an angle of 0), the elements are supposed to move from the left off-screen to the right off-screen and then reappear on the left, creating a loop. For diagonal movement (spaceships), the expectation was similar, with the elements moving in a diagonal path across the screen and then reappearing from the opposite side they exited.
What I Tried:
I implemented a conditional logic within my GSAP animation to distinguish between horizontal and diagonal movements. For the horizontal case, the animation starts with the element off-screen on the left and moves it across to exit on the right. I then used the onRepeat callback to reset the element's position to its starting point off-screen on the left.
For diagonal movements, I calculated the deltaX and deltaY to ensure the element moves in the correct diagonal direction and distance based on the specified angle. Again, I relied on onRepeat to reset the element's position, aiming for a seamless re-entry from the opposite side.
Expected Outcome:
I expected each element to continuously loop across the screen in its respective path — horizontally for clouds and diagonally for spaceships. The key was for them to reappear seamlessly from the opposite side they exited, maintaining a constant flow in the animation.
Actual Result:
While the initial movement across the screen works as expected, the repositioning does not. Instead of reappearing from the opposite side, each element resets to its original starting position. This breaks the continuity of the loop, causing a noticeable jump in the animation rather than a smooth transition.
This issue is crucial for the visual effect I'm aiming for, and despite various adjustments to my approach, including tweaking the onRepeat logic and experimenting with different GSAP properties, the problem persists. I'm looking for insights or alternative methods to achieve the seamless looping effect for both types of movements.
